# Where in Judaism does it describe the journey of the soul in the afterlife?

Tags: jewish-books, mysticism-kabbalah, soul, zohar, afterlife

Where in Judaism does it describe the journey of the soul in the afterlife? Sources, that I am looking for stem from kabbalah teaching or the zohar. Also,I am searching for primary sources, so if they are in hebrew a translation as well as the hebrew text would be much appreciated. Otherwise I can translate it.

Comment: If they're in Hebrew, then you want a translation; otherwise, you can translate it. So… you know every language except Hebrew?

Comment: Correct lol, I will fix that

Comment: Duplicate of http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/47936?

Comment: see [here](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/69016/11501) for some relevant material

Comment: See chapter 87 of the Minchat Yehuda. http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=33796&pgnum=80
 -- Also available in English: http://www.amazon.com/Rabbi-Yehuda-Fetaya-Minhat-Hardcover/dp/B00SB1AG7W/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1458894653&sr=8-2&keywords=minhat+yehuda

Answer (score 0):

here's something by Rabbi Yirmiyahu Ulman

> The Zohar says that before death a person gets a preview of his
>   portion in the soul world: “When a man is about to die, and judgment
>   hovers about him so he would depart from the world, a supernal spirit
>   is added to him that he did not have during his lifetime. When it
>   hovers about him and cleaves to him, he is able to see what he never
>   saw in his days, due to the additional spirit in him. When the spirit
>   is added to him…his eyes are opened to the sight they have just seen,
>   and…if he has a son, the son should be the first to put his hand over
>   his eyes and close them. As it says, ‘And Yosef shall put his hand on
>   your eyes,’ for another unholy sight is come before him and the eye
>   that beheld the supernal holy sight must not look at the other sight”
>   (Zohar, VaYechi).
>
> Then the Angel of Death appears: “It descends and stands at his feet
>   with a sharp sword in his hand. The person lifts his eyes and sees the
>   house walls radiant with fire. At the same time, he sees him, full
>   with eyes, dressed in burning fire in front of the man…There are three
>   drops on his sword. When he sees him, his entire body and spirit
>   tremble and his heart does not rest, being the king of the entire
>   body. Then his spirit travels throughout his organs and takes leave
>   from them like a man who takes leave from his friend to go
>   elsewhere…The person shudders for fear and wishes to hide but does not
>   have the capability. When he realizes that he is powerless, he opens
>   his eyes and he has to look at him with his eyes open. He then gives
>   over his life and soul” (Zohar, Naso; Avoda Zara, 20b).
>
> The departed soul is then escorted by angels, departed tzaddikim, and
>   departed relatives and friends...

from http://ohr.edu/yhiy/article.php/2488
see there for more