# Does the hell exist?

Tags: sin, reward-punishment

Does the hell exist? As in the book of Isaiah, there is a reference to "fire" that is not "quenched".

Isaiah 66:24

> "And they shall go forth, and look upon the carcasses of the men that have rebelled against Me; for their worm shall not die, neither shall their fire be quenched; and they shall be an abhorring unto all flesh."

Comment: The concept of reward and consequence is pretty fundamental in Judaism. I’m not sure your question: whether there is a concept of Hell in Judaism, or whether this verse in Isaiah is a reference to it.

Comment: I wonder if there is a concept of Hell in Judaism

Comment: So the short answer is yes, but not in the sense that Christians talk about it. Maybe a better translation is “purgatory.” If I have time I’ll post a full answer with sources.

Comment: so, we always end up in paradise?

Comment: Related if not duplicate: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/4467/13438

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/7805/9643

Comment: ok. Then, I will post a question asking about the concept of "purgatory" in Judaism

Comment: I didn’t say we always end up in Paradise. The general idea is that as a soul sullies itself with sin, it’s no longer able to connect with G-d. For those who cannot fully cleanse themselves in this world, they’re cleansed in the next world. Some people do sins which are so damaging to their soul that they completely cut themselves off from G-d; those people aren’t even able to be cleansed in purgatory. Depending on the sin, they may spend eternity there, or they may cease to be after they die.